# Call function from other class in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I am trying to call a function from another class in my sprite kit/ swift game with this code:

```
class StarNode: GameObjectNode {
    override func collisionWithBall(ball: SKNode) -> Bool {
        endGame()

        return true
    }
}
```

This function is in another class:

```
func endGame() {
    gameOver = true
    GameFile.sharedInstance.saveState()

    let reveal = SKTransition.fadeWithDuration(0.5)
    let endGameScene = GameOverScene(size: self.size)
    self.view!.presentScene(endGameScene, transition: reveal)
}
```

But when I call **endGame()** I get this message: *Missing argument for parameter #1 in call*.

I've tried to get it work but with no success. What can I do to get it work?

Answer (score 2):

Protocols is probably the best way to communicate between classes, especially if you want to keep your code the way it is.

Above the starNode class you add your protocol

```
protocol StarNodeDelegate: class {
    func endGame()
}
```

than you add a property to the starNode class

```
weak var delegate: StarNodeDelegate?
```

So now your starNode class should look like this.

```
protocol StarNodeDelegate: class {
     func endGame()
} 

class StarNode: GameObjectNode {

weak var delegate: StarNodeDelegate?    


override func collisionWithBall(ball: SKNode) -> Bool {
    delegate?.endGame()

    return true
  }
}
```

Now in the scene where the collision happens and the gameOver func is I presume you have an instance of starNode created to get access to the StarNode class you made.

eg.

```
let starNode = StarNode(...
```

So now you need make that class confirm to the protocol you created.

```
class GameScene: SKScene, StarNodeDelegate {

}
```

than in ViewDidLoad after you created your starNode instance you add this code

```
starNode.delegate = self // telling the scene to confirm to the protocol
```

and voila your

```
func endGame()
```

will get called.

Answer (score 0):

To call method of another class you first need to create object of that(another) class, and class function with that object.

Something like this,

Suppose class name  be **AnotherClass** in which your endGame() function is there.

```
class StarNode: GameObjectNode {
override func collisionWithBall(ball: SKNode) -> Bool {

 let obj = AnotherClass()
 obj.endGame()
  return true
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but when I use this code I get this message: "Cannot invoke initializer for type "GameScene" with no arguments"

Comment: Check initializer (i.e init) method  of your GameScene class , it must be having some argument, so while initializing your class, you need to pass those parameters, If still not clear let me know, i will give you some link.

Comment: I don't think this is the solution the OP is looking for. The instance of `AnotherClass` in this example (I presume, the `GameScene` in OP:s app) is already initialized, and---imperatively---not "active". With the solution above you create a new non-relevant `GameScene` instance and try to call `.endGame()` on this new instance. It's comparable to creating a random `MyViewController` instance in an app to try access some method in the _actual_ `MyViewController` instance that is currently not the scene in the app. Instead of this approach, I suggest using delegates between the two classes.

Comment: @dfri As code provided by Koffman calls endGame() method without instance, so I thought he is not having instance of AnotherClass, that's why I suggested this

Comment: @AjayKumar It's somewhat inferable from the code context that the class containing `.endGame()` probably in itself contains instances of `StarNode`, and not the other way around. Anyway, you should probably ask the OP for more context if you wish to help him, but my guess is the answer will boil down to delegate callbacks from `StarNode` objects to the class which holds `endGame()` method.

Comment: Mat Koffman If you already have instance of GameScene class then you can call endGame method on that instance instead of creating new instance again. And if you want endGame() method to be called whenever collisionWithBAll() method triggers, yes you can use delegation, if you are not clear about delegation you can refer this link http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/swift-from-scratch-delegation-and-properties--cms-23445